# Openapi discriminator without propertyname

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I need inheritance only with one field in super class, so propertyName is no need. Is anyway to ignore propertyName?

```
Base:
      type: object
      discriminator:
        propertyName: useless
      required:
        - id
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 1
```

Response like

```
"useless":"subtype", "id":1
```

And throws error like

```
Unrecognized field "useless"
```

I need inheritance only with id, without field propertyName, is anyway to do it?
Or make propertyName as integer id?